# Build Angular app to single HTML file with inline scripts and styles

Tags: angular, webpack, bundling-and-minification

I need to build my Angular app to a single HTML file with inline scripts and styles. Angular by default builds several js files and one css file and add them to my index.html via the src attribute.

I found a plugin called `html-webpack-inline-source-plugin` but it doesn't do anything. (Probably because of angular?)

Does anyone know another way to build an angular app into a single file with webpack or if there is another package to do so? I already did some research but I did not find a solution.

Thank you in advance!

***EDIT:***

I tried it with the following custom webpack config but it doesnt change the output.

**custom-webpack.config.js**

```
var HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin = require('html-webpack-inline-source-plugin');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inlineSource: '.(js|css)$'
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin()
    ]
}
```

Comment: Guess you mean angular-cli when saying angular. Angular-cli uses webpack internally -- you can use webpack directly, you can build  whatever with webpack, but you'll need to configure it yourself.

Comment: Yes, I mean angular-cli. I tried it with a custom webpack configuration and the before-mentioned `html-webpack-inline-source-plugin` but it does not seem to be applied, since the output is the same as without.

Comment: Can you put a `console.log` in `custom-webpack.config.js` to be sure that the file use used ?

Comment: Yes and it is being used. I see the log when I call `ng build --prod`.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having same issue as you

Answer (score 0):

i couldnt find any solution, so i had to write a script

```
const args = process.argv;

// angular source
const sourceDirectory = args[2]

// directory where you want to build.
const buildDirectory = args[3]

const fs = require('fs-extra');

console.log("running build script for source directory " + sourceDirectory);

console.log("Removing existing build directory " + buildDirectory)
fs.removeSync(buildDirectory);

console.log("copying angular build files to directory " + buildDirectory)
!fs.existsSync(buildDirectory) && fs.mkdirSync(buildDirectory);

// copy all the files from source to build directory and make manipulations.
fs.copySync(sourceDirectory, buildDirectory)


// find the html file, replace script tags with inline script.
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const {JSDOM} = jsdom;

let indexFilePath = buildDirectory + "/index.html";
const htmlSource = fs.readFileSync(indexFilePath)
const dom = new JSDOM(htmlSource.toString());

const scriptTags = Array.from(dom.window.document.getElementsByTagName("script"))
const filesToRemove = []
scriptTags.map((e) => {
  let scriptFile = buildDirectory + "/" + e.getAttribute("src");
  if (scriptFile) {
    filesToRemove.push(scriptFile)
    const source = fs.readFileSync(scriptFile)
    e.removeAttribute("src")
    e.removeAttribute("type")
    e.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript")
    e.innerHTML = source.toString()
  }
})


const styleTags = Array.from(dom.window.document.getElementsByTagName("link"))
const isUrl = string => {
  try {
    return Boolean(new URL(string));
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}

styleTags.map((e) => {
  const rel = e.getAttribute("rel")
  const href = e.getAttribute("href")
  const media = e.getAttribute("media")
  if (rel === "stylesheet" && !isUrl(href) && media === "print") {
    // Remove the stylesheet
    e.parentElement.removeChild(e)
    let styleFile = buildDirectory + "/" + href;
    console.log("inlining css file " + styleFile)
    // Add the stylesheet to dom as inline.
    const style = dom.window.document.createElement("style")
    style.innerHTML = fs.readFileSync(styleFile).toString()
    dom.window.document.body.appendChild(style)
    filesToRemove.push(styleFile)
  }

})


console.log("going to remove inlined script and style files")

filesToRemove.map((file) => {
  console.log("removing " + file)
  fs.removeSync(file);
})

// rewrite index.html.
fs.writeFileSync(indexFilePath, dom.serialize())
```

and add it to package.json like this

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --output-hashing=none",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "package": "node build-scripts/index.js dist/{{YOUR_ANGULAR_PROJECT_NAME}}/  dist-inline/",
    "bundle": "yarn build && yarn package"
  },
```

then call `yarn bundle`